# How to know what voltage to apply in hydrogen gas tub to obtain the spectrum?

Tags: experimental-physics, atomic-physics

Generally to detect the hydrogen spectrum people uses the hydrogen gas tube as a light source. How people knows the right voltage to apply to the tube in order to obtain the hydrogen atomic spectrum.
What I mean is this, if you apply low voltage then we would not be able to dissociate the $H_2$ molecules and so  so atomic spectrum. If the voltage is to high the atoms will be totally ionized. How people knows the right voltage?

Answer (score 1):

For any gas, there is a well-known *breakdown voltage* at which it switches from being a good insulator to a good conductor. This "starting voltage" is the minimum voltage required to start the glow discharge. You can find breakdown voltages for different gases in a handbook of high-voltage engineering.

Then, to prevent the gas from immediately turning into a fully-ionized plasma at high temperature, the current flowing into the gas through the electrodes is limited electronically by something called a *ballast circuit*. It takes less voltage to sustain a glow discharge that it did to start it, and the ballast circuit's job is to allow the source voltage to drop down to the *sustaining voltage* after the glow is *started*.